# Checkboxes In Gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a requirement where i have to design a grid like the snap shot.
All field are static field but problem arise for me in checkbox section in selecting all row checkboxs and selecting all column checkboxes.

Please help how to achieve it?[image]

Comment: Would be nice if your could show your html and what you achieved so far.

Comment: add unique class for each row and colomn and use jquery to check the specific row or colomn

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a table and your check-boxes located at that table cells (one check-box per cell).

1st of all you need get index of column like so:

```
var $td = $(this).closest('td');
var index = $(this).closest('td').parent().children().index($td);
```

and then you need get all td's within that column, find check-boxes and set their state to one you just clicked like:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child('+index+')').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
```